# Dictionary of arrays assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make that each id in `cert` will have an array of strings in them. So for each id I will write something, and it will print it in a `for` loop after. That's the basic idea.

```
cert[id] = [] # array assignment

for x in cert[id[]]: # array scan
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Do you care what the values of the `id` field are? In that case you'd be better off making a dictionary of lists. Or do you not care what the `id` field values are?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508657/multidimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you would rather want is a dictionary, which is just a hash map, with key-value pairs. For example, to initialize an empty dictionary:

```
cert = {}
```

or

```
cert = dict()
```

Then to populate the dictionary using an id as the key and a list of strings as the value:

```
cert["id"] = ["1234", "4321", "1111"]
```

And then if you wanted to iterate through the list inside the dictionary:

```
for num in cert["id"]:
    print(num)
```

The structure of the dictionary looks like this:

```
cert = { "id": ["1234", "4321", "1111"] }
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if I misunderstood your question! Thanks.

Comment: thanks , i got confused with dictionaries and arrays, this helped.

Comment: Okay sweet! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that (1) `cert` already exists, and (2) `id` also already exists as an index into `cert`. If so, then do this:

```
# assign something
cert[id] = ["a", "list", "of", "strings"]

# iterate through each element of the recently-assigned something, and do whatever
for x in cert[id]:
    ...
```

If you want to refer to a specific element, you can do this:

```
print(cert[id][1])
# "list"
```

---

Don't get too confused by nested lists - it's just an element of a list that itself holds another list. A list-of-lists:

```
cert = [
    ["the",    "quick", "brown", "fox"],  # index 0 of cert
    ["jumped", "over",  "the",   "lazy"], # index 1 of cert
    ...
    #   ^        ^        ^        ^
    #   0        1        2        3      <-- indices of sublists
]
```

To get the word `"lazy"` from this, you would first get index 1 of `cert`, and then get index 3 of that sublist:

```
print(cert[1][3])
# "lazy"
```

Any individual list element, considered in isolation, behaves like a regular variable (note that you could replace `cert[id]` above with any other variable name and the code would still make just as much sense).